# Template block recursion with Jinja

Tags: google-app-engine, templates, jinja2

I'm new to Jinja and just trying to evaluate whether it'll do what I need.

Say I have a list of elements, with each element containing a dictionary of key/value pairs.
I want Jinja to iterate on blocks for each element in the list, and use the block contents to print the key/value pairs for each dictionary.

(I say recursion in the title because my actual implementation uses recursion.  With iteration it is the same concept though, so I use it here for simplicity).

So, my naive attempt at this would be something like this (this is more or less pseudocode):

block.html:

```
{% extends base.html %}
{% block element %}
    <do some fancy printing with the current dictionary here>
{% endblock %}
```

base.html:

```
{% for item in seq %}
    <li>{% block element %}{% endblock %}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

.py file (based off GoogleAppEngine Jinja implementation):

```
myDict = { 'seq': [{'keyA0': 'valueA0', 'keyA1': 'valueA1'}, 
                   {'keyB0': 'valueB0', 'keyB1': 'valueB1'}] }


template = JINJA_ENVIRONMENT.get_template('block.html')
self.response.write(template.render(myDict))
```

I'm not sure how to structure this to do what I want.  I want 'instances' of the blocks to have the appropriate dictionary from the list to print the values, to output something like this:

```
Entry0:
keyA0: valueA0
keyA1: valueA1

Entry1:
keyB0: valueB0
keyB1: valueB1
```

But I'm not sure how to pass each block the data it needs.  Is this possible with Jinja?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code looks ok to me. You have created a list of block elements. For every block you iterate through the block dict. You can use a jinja loop.index to render the entries like "Entry0:"

Example (without the markup) :

```
Entry{{ loop.index }}:
{% for key, value in item.iteritems() %}
     {{ key }} : {{ value }}
{% endfor %}
```